# How do you even give an (openFST-made) FST input? Where does the output go?

Tags: python, shell, fsm, openfst

Before I start, note that I'm using the linux shell (via `using subprocess.call()` from Python), and I am using openFST.

I've been sifting through documents and questions about openFST, but I cannot seem to find an answer to this question: how does one actually give input to an openFST-defined, compiled and composed FST? Where does the output go? Do I simply execute 'fstproject'? If so, how would I, say, give it a string to transduce, and print the various transductions when the end-state(s) have been reached?

I apologize if this question seems obvious. I'm not very familiar with openFST as of yet.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One way is to create your machine that performs the transformation.
A very simple example would be to upper case a string.

M.wfst

```
0 0 a A
0 0 b B
0 0 c C
0
```

The accompanying symbols file contains a line for for each symbols of the alphabet. Note 0 is reserved for null (epsilon) transitions and has special meaning in many of the operations.

M.syms

```
<epsilon> 0
a 1
b 2
c 3
A 4
B 5
C 6
```

Then compile the machine

```
fstcompile --isymbols=M.syms --osymbols=M.syms M.wfst > M.ofst
```

For an input string "abc" create a linear chain automata, this is a left-to-right chain with an arc for each character. This is an acceptor so we only need a column for the
input symbols.

I.wfst

```
0 1 a
1 2 b
2 3 c
3
```

Compile as an acceptor

```
fstcompile --isymbols=M.syms --acceptor I.wfst > I.ofst
```

Then compose the machines and print

```
fstcompose I.ofst M.ofst | fstprint --isymbols=M.syms --osymbols=M.syms
```

This will give the output

```
0   1   a   A
1   2   b   B
2   3   c   C
3
```

The output of fstcompose is a lattice of all transductions of the input string. (In this case there is only one). If M.ofst is more complicated  fstshortestpath can be used to extract n-strings using the flags --unique -nshortest=n. This output is again a transducer,  you could  either  scrap  the output of fstprint, or use C++ code and the OpenFst library to run depth first search to extract the strings.

Inserting fstproject --project_output will convert the output to an acceptor containing only the output labels.

```
fstcompose I.ofst M.ofst | fstproject --project_output |  fstprint --isymbols=M.syms --osymbols=M.syms
```

Gives the following

```
0  1  A  A
1  2  B  B
2  3  C  C
3
```

This is an acceptor because the input and output labels are the same, the --acceptor options can be used to generate more succinct output.

```
 fstcompose I.ofst M.ofst | fstproject --project_output |  fstprint --isymbols=M.syms --acceptor
```

Comment: This is a great answer and the examples are very useful! Thank you!

Comment: I find it slightly unbelievable that openfst doesn't provide a way to create the 'linear chain automata'.

Comment: Is there any way to do this in python?

Answer (score 3):

The example from Paul Dixon is great. As the OP uses Python I thought I'd add a quick example on how you can "run" transducers with [Open FST's Python wrapper](http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/FST/PythonExtension). It's a shame that you can not create "linear chain automata" with Open FST, but it's simple to automate as seen below:

```
def linear_fst(elements, automata_op, keep_isymbols=True, **kwargs):
    """Produce a linear automata."""
    compiler = fst.Compiler(isymbols=automata_op.input_symbols().copy(), 
                            acceptor=keep_isymbols,
                            keep_isymbols=keep_isymbols, 
                            **kwargs)

    for i, el in enumerate(elements):
        print >> compiler, "{} {} {}".format(i, i+1, el)
    print >> compiler, str(i+1)

    return compiler.compile()

def apply_fst(elements, automata_op, is_project=True, **kwargs):
    """Compose a linear automata generated from `elements` with `automata_op`.

    Args:
        elements (list): ordered list of edge symbols for a linear automata.
        automata_op (Fst): automata that will be applied.
        is_project (bool, optional): whether to keep only the output labels.
        kwargs:
            Additional arguments to the compiler of the linear automata .
    """
    linear_automata = linear_fst(elements, automata_op, **kwargs)
    out = fst.compose(linear_automata, automata_op)
    if is_project:
        out.project(project_output=True)
    return out
```

Let's define a simple Transducer that uppercases the letter "a":

```
f_ST = fst.SymbolTable()
f_ST.add_symbol("<eps>", 0)
f_ST.add_symbol("A", 1)
f_ST.add_symbol("a", 2)
f_ST.add_symbol("b", 3)
compiler = fst.Compiler(isymbols=f_ST, osymbols=f_ST, keep_isymbols=True, keep_osymbols=True)

print >> compiler, "0 0 a A"
print >> compiler, "0 0 b b"
print >> compiler, "0"
caps_A = compiler.compile()
caps_A
```

[image]

Now we can simply apply the transducer using :

```
apply_fst(list("abab"), caps_A)
```

Output:
[image]

To see how to use it for an acceptor look at my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54067509/6232494)

Answer (score 0):

Updating Yann Dubois answer to python3:

```py
import pywrapfst as fst

print("")
f_ST: fst.SymbolTable


def linear_fst(elements, automata_op, keep_isymbols=True, **kwargs):
    """Produce a linear automata."""
    compiler = fst.Compiler(
        isymbols=f_ST,  # There should be some way to get this from automata_op
        acceptor=keep_isymbols,
        keep_isymbols=keep_isymbols,
        **kwargs
    )
    for i, el in enumerate(elements):
        print("{} {} {}".format(i, i + 1, el), end="", file=compiler)
    print(str(i + 1), end="", file=compiler)
    lf = compiler.compile()
    return lf


def apply_fst(elements, automata_op, print_la=True, is_project=False, **kwargs):
    """Compose a linear automata generated from `elements` with `automata_op`.
    Args:
        elements (list): ordered list of edge symbols for a linear automata.
        automata_op (Fst): automata that will be applied.
        print_la (bool, optional): print linear automata as text representation
        is_project (str, optional): whether to keep only the "input" or "output" labels.
        kwargs: Additional arguments to the compiler of the linear automata .
    """
    linear_automata = linear_fst(elements, automata_op, **kwargs)
    if print_la:
        print("Linear Automata:\n", linear_automata)
    out = fst.compose(linear_automata, automata_op)
    if is_project:
        out.project("output")
    return out


f_ST = fst.SymbolTable()
f_ST.add_symbol("<eps>", 0)
f_ST.add_symbol("A", 1)
f_ST.add_symbol("a", 2)
f_ST.add_symbol("b", 3)
compiler = fst.Compiler(
    isymbols=f_ST, osymbols=f_ST, keep_isymbols=True, keep_osymbols=True
)

print("0 0 a A", end="", file=compiler)
print("0 0 b b", end="", file=compiler)
print("0", end="", file=compiler)
caps_A = compiler.compile()
print("Uppercase Transducer with", caps_A.num_states(), "states:\n", caps_A)

caps_I = apply_fst(list("abab"), caps_A)
print("Output:\n", caps_I)
```

This prints:

```
Uppercase Transducer with 1 states:
 0  0   a   A
0   0   b   b
0

Linear Automata:
 0  1   a   2
1   2   b   3
2   3   a   2
3   4   b   3
4

Output:
 0  1   a   A
1   2   b   b
2   3   a   A
3   4   b   b
4
```