# Python Multiple regex Patterns string reassignment using re.sub

Tags: python, regex, variable-assignment

I have a string to which I'd like to identify more than 10 possible patterns and replace them without using a `For` loop

string example =

`text = congrats! first recharge of USD 661 is successful & your service is valid till 2019-10-19. dial 0123456789 or click bit.ly/vf_asdqweerw in 46 hours to avail your reward.`

expected outcome =

`congrats! first recharge of USD <Amount> is successful & your service is valid till <Date>. dial <PhoneNumber> or click <Link> in 46 hours to avail your reward.`

I have a dictionary of regex patterns for each value:

```
dct = {
      r"((http(s?)://)|(bit\\.l)|(www.)).+?(?=[, ]|$)": <Link>,
      r"(\d{2}[-/.])(\w{1,3}|\d{2})[-/.](\d{2,4})\b"  : <Date>,
      .....
}
```

tried [How can I do multiple substitutions using regex in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175142/how-can-i-do-multiple-substitutions-using-regex-in-python) but with no success

my current solution uses

```
for k,v in dct.items():
    text = re.sub(k,v,text)
```

I need something more scalable.

Comment: if you find my answer useful, could you please mark the question as answered (the gray tick on the left of the answer)?

Answer (score 0):

The approach that would best fit your need is to use finite-state transducers. `re.sub` is like a building block of FST and it would be best for you to use them all efficiently at once.

There is a [`pynini`](http://www.opengrm.org/twiki/bin/view/GRM/Pynini) Python library that is an [interface](http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/FST/PythonExtension) into [OpenFST](http://www.openfst.org/) renowned C++ implementation. It is [quite difficult to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45213112/why-openfst-does-not-seem-to-have-run-or-accept-or-transduce-command) and requires some training to understand the underlying concepts. A relatively good introduction is [this one](https://www.oreilly.com/content/how-to-get-superior-text-processing-in-python-with-pynini/).

The approach would be roughly something like:

```
import pynini
mappings = [pynini.transducer(k, v) for k, v in dct.items()]
kvmap = pynini.union(*mappings)

def multi_substitute(in_str):
    return pynini.shortestpath(pynini.compose(in_str, kvmap)).stringify()
```